# Adding Web Reference changes IList to Array[]

Tags: c#

When i add a web reference to my client app, the web reference classes properties are changed from ILists to arrays. So snippet below. Would there be a reason for this? I just like working with ILists more since they are so dynamic. Could i change this on n client side to ILists?

Server side

```
    [DataMember]
    public IList<Lookup> Lookup { get; set; }
```

Client side

```
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public FANDI.Data.BusinessObjects.Lookup[] Lookup
    {
        get
        {
            return this.LookupField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.LookupField = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, i found what i believe to be the solution. When creating the proxy class with svcutil.exe you can pass in what type should be used for the collectionType. /collectionType:<type> A fully-qualified or assembly-qualified name of the type to use as a collection data type when code is generated from schemas. (Short Form: /ct) eg. svcutil.exe /a localhost/test/test/mex /o:c:\\dev\\test.cs /config:c:\\dev\\test.config /r:c:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\mscorlib.dll /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Answer (score 2):

A web service reference don't support Lists, only arrays.

If you use `Service Reference` instead of `Web Reference` you can specify the collection type to use.

Comment: What if i use a proxy class, could i change it then?

Comment: If you generate the proxy either with Add Service Reference in VS, or use svcutil /collectionType: you can achieve the getting it as a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
public FANDI.Data.BusinessObjects.Lookup[] Lookup
```

That line of code suggests that it is an array of lookup objects (Lookup[]).

Can you not change this to

```
public IList<FANDI.Data.BusinessObjects.Lookup> Lookup
```