# Use a Generic List in a Web Service?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, generics

I have a class of properties which is being used as part of a web service. The Class has list of another class as one of its properties:

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class LessonPlans
    Public Property Teacher As String
    Public Property RoomNumber As String
    Public Property Subject As String
    Public Property Students As List(Of Student)
End Class

<Serializable()> _
Public Class Student
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
End Class
```

When I work with the LessonPlans class on the local application, I have no problem doing the following:

```
Dim _NewLesson As New LessonPlans
_NewLesson.RoomNumber = "5"
_NewLesson.Subject = "English"
_NewLesson.Teacher = "Mr Smith"

Dim _Students As New List(Of Student)

Dim _NewStudent As New Student
_NewStudent.FirstName = "James"
_NewStudent.LastName = "Jones"

_Students.Add(_NewStudent)

_NewLesson.Students = _Students
```

However, when I try to add the following line on the application that consumes the web service:

```
_NewLesson.Students = _Students
```

I get an error:
Error 6
Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of WindowsApplication1.ws_lessons.Students)' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of WindowsApplication1.ws_lessons.Students'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Web Reference changes IList to Array\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370164/adding-web-reference-changes-ilist-to-array)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the properties of your reference to the WS and under "advanced" settings check out whether you expect a list or an array

Comment: How do you access the advanced settings of a Web Reference? I can see the advanced settings of a Service Reference but not of a Web Reference.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that while there is a rather complicated way of achieving what I need above, it is far easier to work with a Generic List from a web service by importing it into your project as a Service Reference and not as a Web Reference. The Web Reference functionality in the newer versions of Visual Studio is outdated and seems to have been superseded by Service Reference.